# What is the period of time that carrier_down_count represents?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is the integer output the number of times the link has been down since 00:00 server time, in the last 24 hours or what exactly?

The kernel.org site only provides this information:

```
What:       /sys/class/net/<iface>/carrier_down_count
Date:       Jan 2018
KernelVersion:  4.16
Contact:    netdev@vger.kernel.org
Description:
        32-bit unsigned integer counting the number of times the link has
        been down
```

Comment: Hi Chris. It seems that you did not use the code tag appropriately and some information was not being shown on your question. I've fixed it, but you could also do it by editing your question ok?

Answer (score 0):

That file shows the count of times there has been a "carrier down", as like "cable removed", event on a given interface since it has been added to the system. Just as described, there is no time reset mechanic in place. I have tried to overwrite that value directly with `echo 0 > /sys/class/net/<iface>/carrier_down_count`, without success.

You may see it reset as you reboot your system (all devices are "readded" as the system boots) or if you remove the device and add it again, as could be done by the `ip link delete` and `ip link add` commands.

In short, tipically it will represent the number of carrier down events since the last boot of the system.